# Using composite Primary Key in a collection with high amount of update

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with about 10,000 documents and the structure of documents are like this:

```
{
    "_id" : NUUID("a23ad36e-b0ca-4fa2-9d36-163223f26142"),
    "Field_1" : NUUID("451a4cd9-3dab-4b5d-b792-bb81f0950a75"),
    "Field_2" : null,
    "Field_3" : NUUID("31ab892f-99c1-4e33-959b-12d0a90a3d3d"),
    "Field_4" : 1,
    "Field_5" : "AAF12A0A4D18",
    "Field_6" : ISODate("2018-05-30T22:40:05.389Z"),
    "Field_7" : ISODate("2018-06-31T20:02:35.947Z"),
    "Field_8" : NumberLong(9300)
}
```

My application updates documents in this collection every second. Is it better to use a composite Primary Key for this collection or just use normal Primary Key and define compound Index instead?

Comment: What would be your reasoning for using a composite key?

Comment: To find each object to update, I need to find the specific object based on 4 parameters, if I use composite primary key, I think I can find that record faster and I do not need to define a compound index because it will be _id and it will be indexed automatically. On the other hand this collection is growing and it will take more disc space.

Comment: The growing collection is a concern when using a compound index as well so you might have to consider building your index in the background. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#index-creation-background

Comment: Thank you for the link. But I think this goes for standalone database, I am using replica set.